# SQL injection and escaping special characters

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I accept data from TinyMCE. I get into difficulties when I copy and paste from a site such as this:

```
http://www.rlslog.net/category/games/pc/
```

I use the following functions to prevent an SQL injection and escape special characters that if ruin my whole page once I output the inserted text.

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
$author= mysql_real_escape_string($author);

$data =htmlentities($data);
$title =htmlentities($title);   
$author =htmlentities($author); 

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `easy_db`.`article` (`Title`,  `Article`, `Topics`, `author`, `page`, tpage ) VALUES('$title', '$data', '$topic', '$author', '$page','$tpage')")  or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
```

What I get when I output the data is my html text (which isnt the output from the database) looking like that:

```
×›×•×ª×¨×ª ×”×™×•×
```

I turend  magic_quotes_gpc off in my php.ini

```
magic_quotes_gpc
Default Value: Off
Development Value: Off
Production Value: Off
```

Here is how the text that I put looks like when refering to it in phpmyadmin:

```
skidrow%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe></p>\r\n<p class=\"comments_link\" style=\"padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0px; line-height: 19px; margin: 0px;\"><a style=\"color:

c02e13; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;\" title=\"Comment on Orcs Must Die Fix-SKIDROW\"
href=\"http://www.rlslog.net/orcs-must-die-fix-skidrow/#respond\">Comments(0)</a></p>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div style=\"padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 40px; margin: 0px;\"><iframe style=\"padding: 0px; margin: 0px;\" src=\"http://www.roadcomponentsdb.com/300.htm\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"NO\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\"></iframe></div>\r\n<p id=\"nextlinks\" style=\"padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 20px; margin: 0px;\"><strong style=\"padding: 0px; margin: 0px;\">Previous post:</strong>&nbsp;<a style=\"color: #c02e13; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;\" href=\"http://www.rlslog.net/musclemag-international-%e2%80%93-december-2011-p2p/\">MuscleMag International &ndash; December 2011-P2P</a></p>
```

The question is why is it happening? how do I prevent it? and do I do enough to prevent an sql injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET NAMES 'utf8'` is altering your data.

Take a look at [this MySQL forum link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,46870,47245#msg-47245). He provides a fairly good description of what's going on. Short description: the conversion process is confused as to what it should be reading the characters as.

Comment: if you look at my code, I already set it. Is there another way to encode that string..any php or mysql function to eliminate that effect from happening

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd You have to remove that statement.

Comment: It doesnt seem to make any improvement, I still get..×›×•×ª×¨×ª ×”×™×•× in all the text elements apart from teh text I output

Comment: No sorry, It has improved the situation..now it stopped doing so. Could you tell me about the sql injection bit..Am I safe from an injection

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Yes you should be. Escaping the strings and removing HTML covers pretty much all injection attempts.